# How to use a longtable with only one entry in the list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, longtable

I'm using longtable to spread my table over three pages. Unfortunately the caption is also added three times to the list of tables. Is is possible to have it displayed only once?

Comment: How do you add the caption exactly? Please add [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows it. I probably use `\caption` several times. Try to replace it all but the first with `\caption*`. This might require the `caption` package.

Comment: i simply use only one time \caption{My Caption above Table} I'll try to make a MWE. But in fact I have \begin{longtable}{r r} \caption{xxx} ....

Comment: @Martin: `\caption*` inside longtables is offered by the `longtable` package itself. So no need for the `caption` package. (This differs from `\caption*` inside floating environments, this one is offered by the `caption` package)

Comment: axel: but this time the caption disappears totally from my toc. I would like to have it displayed only once, not three times. It prints the caption as much as the table takes space in pages here

Comment: @adnc: Then you used `\endhead` instead of `\endfirsthead`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use for the `\endfirsthead` the default `\caption` and for `\endhead` the starred version of `\caption`.

Comment: Same here, for the starred version of `\caption` inside longtables the `caption` package is not needed.

Comment: did I said something different ... :-))

Comment: `\caption*` does not print the table number. `\caption[]{…}` does print the number but does not make an entry to the list of tables.

Answer (score 10):

In case you want a numbered caption on follow-up table pages, use

```
\caption{<Caption Text>}
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{<Caption Text>}
\endhead
```

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{5}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\section{foo}

\begin{longtable}{c}
\caption{A table}
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{A table}
\endhead
bar \\
bar \\
bar \\
bar \\
bar \\
bar \\
bar \\
bar \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the \usepackage{tabularx} to solve the problem. The following code will produce a list of tables with a caption added only once.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2cm}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.2cm}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{4cm}}
    \caption{Table A} \label{tab:Table A} \\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Sample 1} & \textbf{Sample 2} & \textbf{Sample 3} \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Table A} \label{Table A} \\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Sample 1} & \textbf{Sample 2} & \textbf{Sample 3} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 6 \\
    2 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 8 & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Unfortunately; `tabularx` is not an environment for multi-page tables.