# Three different captions: longtable

Tags: captions, longtable

My problem is that I have tables that are three pages long. Thus, I would like to have three different captions when using the `longtable package`.

The similar question [How to use a longtable with only one entry in the list of tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26024/how-to-use-a-longtable-with-only-one-entry-in-the-list-of-tables) does not solve my problem. As far as I know this is how we could use `longtable` regarded this matter:

```
\caption{Example of longtable}
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Continued}
\endhead
```

However, if the table occupies three pages, so that's how the captions are:

> Table 2.1 - Example of longtable (page 1)
>
> Table 2.1 - Continued (page 2)
>
> Table 2.1 - Continued (page 3)

In other words, I can not get different captions for the second and third pages. That's what I want and that's the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We closed your question as it seems to be a duplicate, also to prevent duplicate answers. Please have a look at the answers to the other question linked above. If your question is different, please edit it to show that, we could reopen it for you if desired.

Comment: Sant, I reopened the question now. I also took the liberty to fix some formatting things and brought in a suitable form. You might want to check if it is ok like this. @StefanKottwitz

Answer (score 6):

`longtable` has two settings for the headers of the table: `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead`. The contents of `\endfirsthead` will be saved in the save box `\LT@firsthead` and the contents of `\endhead` in `\LT@head`. If the box `\LT@firsthead` is empty, `longtable` uses the contents of `\LT@head`. The same procedure will be used for the footer. In the same way I defined a `\endsecondhead`

```
\def\endsecondhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@secondhead}
```

To use this command I have to define a new save box which will be set only on the second page.

```
\newbox\LT@secondhead
```

To make sure that only on the second page this box will be used I have to manipulate the output of `longtable`. Therefore I use a simple `\ifvoid` clause.

```
\ifvoid\LT@secondhead
   \copy\LT@head\nobreak
\else
   \box\LT@secondhead\nobreak
\fi
```

`\ifvoid` tests whether the save box `\LT@secondhead` is empty or not. If you set a second head, the box will be printed by `\box`. This command prints the box and clears the box. So on the next page the test above is true. In this way you make sure that when no second head is defined the `\endhead` will be used.

To allow for more than three different headings you must define new save boxes and extend the test.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop,longtable}
\newcounter{count}
\setcounter{count}{1}
\makeatletter
\newbox\LT@secondhead
\def\endsecondhead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@secondhead}
\def\LT@output{%
  \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@Mi
    \ifnum\outputpenalty > -\LT@end@pen
      \LT@err{floats and marginpars not allowed in a longtable}\@ehc
    \else
      \setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
      \ifdim \ht\LT@lastfoot>\ht\LT@foot
        \dimen@\pagegoal
        \advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@lastfoot
        \ifdim\dimen@<\ht\z@
          \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\z@\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
          \@makecol
          \@outputpage
          \ifvoid\LT@secondhead
           \setbox\z@\vbox{\box\LT@head}%
          \else
           \setbox\z@\vbox{\box\LT@secondhead}%
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
      \global\@colroom\@colht
      \global\vsize\@colht
      \vbox
        {\unvbox\z@\box\ifvoid\LT@lastfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@lastfoot\fi}%
    \fi
  \else
    \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
    \@makecol
    \@outputpage
      \global\vsize\@colroom
      \ifvoid\LT@secondhead
         \copy\LT@head\nobreak
      \else
         \box\LT@secondhead\nobreak
      \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\listoftables
\section{section}
\begin{longtable}{c}
\caption{foo}\\\stepcounter{table}\endfirsthead
\caption{foo bar}\\\stepcounter{table}\endsecondhead
\caption{bar}\\\endhead
\whiledo{\value{count} < 100}{\stepcounter{count}
   \arabic{count} \\}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will work only for three page tables, though.

Comment: @egreg: The request were 3 ;-). For more you have to define more boxes which will influence the calculation.

Comment: Maybe you can specify it in your (very clever) answer.