# Longtabu in the list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, longtabu

I am using `longtabu` package to span a large table to multiple pages but my problem is that I get the name of this table for all pages that it span in the list of tables. I need to eliminate this and get only the first page of the `longtabu` referenced in the list of tables. Since I use a template, I can not be sure about the structure of the list of tables and wanted to ask if I can do anything with `longtabu` package. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? Without I could only suggest, that you've added the `\caption` with the entry to the list of tables to the `\endhead` instead of the `\endfirsthead`. In this case the question would be a duplicate to [How to use a longtable with only one entry in the list of tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26024/how-to-use-a-longtable-with-only-one-entry-in-the-list-of-tables).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the tabu-package use the package `longtable` and adapt  the commands of your long table. The tabu package is unmaintained, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121847/4736 .

Comment: Isn't this more a kind of comment than an answer?

Comment: @Schweinebacke What do you think is the difference? Many regulars here really have difficulties in understanding that every information that will solve the issue of the OP is an answer, while everything else might be a comment. I'll never understand why folks answer questions via the comment function. Because of this behaviour, we have 10,000 unsanswered questions in the statistics.

Comment: Because it does not answer how to avoid to get the table entry for all pages instead of only the first one. `longtabu` inherits the `longtable` syntax for head and foot definition. You should at least show, how to make a `longtable` over several pages but with only one entry to the list of tables. But I think, this would be [a duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26024/how-to-use-a-longtable-with-only-one-entry-in-the-list-of-tables).

Comment: @Schweinebacke He is asking about the page in the list of tables, what is connection to head and foot of a table?

Comment: What do you think, why he has entries for every page of the `longtabu` instead of only the first one? Can you show us, how switching to `longtable` would change this?

Comment: @KeksDose: No criticism from me, but we have a lot of questions with unupvoted answers, that is a major portion of that 10000 questions ;-)

Comment: Ok I switched to the longtable and also checked answers in the other question: "How to use a longtable with only one entry in the list of tables". Now problem is solved. I really appreciate your help. Thank you !